# How to call javascript function in console application main method

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

I need to just call javascript function in a console application main method.

Can any one suggest how can I do this?

Comment: what language is your "console application" written in?

Comment: http://jint.codeplex.com/ Jint is a javascript interpreter for .net

Comment: i dont want any interpreter. i need the some code throuh which i can call the javascript function.

Comment: You'll need to provider more details of what you are doing in the javascript.  Plus - why it needs to be javascript.  I don't see how you are going to 'call' a javascript function from c# without an interpreter.

Comment: Wait, are you trying to call a JavaScript function on a browser web page from C#?

Comment: i want to call the javascript function in console application

Comment: is "rewrite the javascript function in C#" an acceptable solution?

Comment: wtf are you trying to do..doing introp with ruby, python still seems reasonable.. but with a web scripting language... what is the world are you doing..?

Comment: Perhaps you should restate the questions, make it longer, list exactly what you are trying to do. Better yet, include code that you have already written and show sample output for what you are trying to accomplish.

People here are ready to help you but first help them understand what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't use an interpreter, then you cannot!
First learn how and where javascript works!

Comment: how to call exe file using Jint - Javascript Interpreter